# Using fwrite() to set a variable in a file

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I have two php files: one is called key.php and the other is the function that validates the key. I want to regularly write to the key.php file and update the key from the validator.php file.

I have this code:

```
 $fp = fopen('key.php', 'w');
 $fwrite = fwrite($fp, '$key = "$newkey"');
```

What I'm trying to do is set the $key variable in the file key.php to the value of $new key which is something like $newkey = 'agfdnafjafl4'; in validator.php.

How can I get this to work (use fwrite to set a pre-existing variable in another file aka overwrite it)?

Comment: And then things went from bad to worse... please reconsider the approach used to solve the *actual* problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$fp = fopen('key.php', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '$key = "' . $newkey . '"');
fclose($fp);
```

This will "overwrite" the variable in a literal sense. However, it won't modify the one you're using in your script as it runs, you'll need to set it (`$key = somevalue`).

More to the point, you really should be using a database or a seperate flat text file for this. Modifying php code like this is just plain ugly.

Comment: and noticce how Chris escapes the single quotes. If you wouldn't escape your key.php would literaly say `$key = "$newkey";` if you're using single quotes PHP won't process any variables within. If you use doubles it would. So having `$test = 'test';` and: `echo "this is a $test";` would echo 'This is test' while `echo 'this is a $test';` would echo 'This is a $test'.

Comment: That's another problem, if you ask me there's a solution given. There's no need for Chris or anyone else to hand in complete working solutions. As the question states $newkey comes from another file it's pretty fair we all assume that Trenton makes sure nothing weird can happen to this variable.

Answer (score 0):

**for_example**, you have YOUR_File.php, and  there is written `$any_varriable='hi Mikl';`

to change that variable to "hi Nicolas", use like the following code:

```
<?php
$filee='YOUR_File.php'; 
        /*read ->*/ $temmp = fopen($filee, "r");   $contennts=fread($temp,filesize($filee)); fclose($temmp);

// here goes your update
$contennts = preg_replace('/\$any_varriable=\"(.*?)\";/', '$any_varriable="hi Jack";', $contennts);
        /*write->*/ $temp =fopen($filee, "w");    fwrite($temp, $contennts);    fclose($temp);
?>
```